# How can I create a firewall which allows me to make application based rules?

Tags: firewall

I do not trust anything, so I want to write my own firewall. I'm not satisfied with the application firewalls in Linux and Windows and the distro firewalls are not adequate for my purposes. I'm frustrated with distro firewalls, most of them like pfSense, OPN Sense, ipfire just seem to give illusion of firewall but all they do is packet filtering. I'm unable to block everything and only allow few websites with it, I have created a rule to block DNS requests, applied that rule and rebooted the firewall distro but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I either have to block everything or allow everything, both of which are undesirable. The sc*mbags seemed to have deliberately made the interface unintuitive to sell service, they claim their firewalls are free but made the interface obtuse, so that they can steal money by selling service.

I'm thinking of writing my own firewall, one of this will be an application which will run on the client system and the other would be standalone distro, both will run together to allow better management. The application on the client will create a special packet signed with the hash of the application, OS, etc and the intermediary firewall distro will check this hash and allow rules and policies to be created based on this hash. Does the TCP/IP protocol allow this?

I have searched the net for resources about network API on Linux, and there are three resources about writing my own firewall, two are questions here and one is netfilter. I don't know anything about TCP/IP protocol, so I don't know if I can use the packets made TCP/IP to achieve this or I have to creatively find a way to create a special packet.

Comment: Don't take this as criticism, but there *seems* to be a gap between your current knowledge/skill levels (as per your own admission) and the requisite knowledge required for the task. If that gap does *indeed* exist, you may want to start with something a little less complex.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm not taking your comment as criticism and I do realize the gaps in my knowledge regarding my endeavor to make my own firewalls. I don't know if the comment you make is based on the frustration with firewall distros or my question about TCP/IP protocol. About my knowledge gap regarding my endeavor to make my own firewalls, I'll learn as I go, and if it requires me to make something simpler, I'll do that. But I realized I program well when I'm pursuing the program I want to make.

Comment: It was your comment about lack of knowledge on the TCP and IP protocols but, provided you realise it'll be a (possibly frustrating at times) learning experience, go for it. I'm a great believer in (temporary) failure being the best teacher :-)